# HTML canvas distorts an image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to make a map at HTML canvas that i can move around on with drag and drop.
But when i drag the map around and draw current frame it appears distorted:

When you see top left corner:

[image: undistorted]

When you drag it down:

[image: distorted]

Image size is 2000x2000
Canvas is 500x500

My draw function.

```
    draw() {
        var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        ctx.drawImage(images['map'], 0 - this.camera[0], 0 - this.camera[1], 2000 - this.camera[0], 2000 - this.camera[1])
```

```js
var prev_mouse_x = null;
var prev_mouse_y = null;
var pressed = false;

function get_pos_in_canvas(canvas, event) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: event.clientX - rect.left,
      y: event.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

document.getElementById('map').onmousedown = event => {
    pressed = true;
    prev_mouse_x = null;
    prev_mouse_y = null;
}

document.getElementById('map').onmousemove = event => {
    if (pressed)
    {
        if (prev_mouse_x != null) {
            var dx = event.pageX - prev_mouse_x;
            var dy = event.pageY - prev_mouse_y;
            move(dx, dy);
        }
        prev_mouse_x = event.pageX;
        prev_mouse_y = event.pageY;
    }
};

document.getElementById('map').onmouseup = event => {
    pressed = false;
}

camera = [0, 0];
var ctx = document.getElementById('map').getContext('2d');

function move(dx, dy) {
    camera[0] -= dx;
    camera[1] -= dy;
}

const image = document.getElementById('source');

function draw(time) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0 - camera[0], 0 - camera[1], 2000 - camera[0], 2000 - camera[1])
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
Example
<br>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="source"
       src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kthr8.jpg">
</div>
<canvas id='map' width=500 height=500></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is how to fix this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only change the x and y positions of your image (translate), no need to change its width and height (fourth and fifth arguments of `drawImage`):

```js
var prev_mouse_x = null;
var prev_mouse_y = null;
var pressed = false;

function get_pos_in_canvas(canvas, event) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: event.clientX - rect.left,
      y: event.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

document.getElementById('map').onmousedown = event => {
    pressed = true;
    prev_mouse_x = null;
    prev_mouse_y = null;
}

document.getElementById('map').onmousemove = event => {
    if (pressed)
    {
        if (prev_mouse_x != null) {
            var dx = event.pageX - prev_mouse_x;
            var dy = event.pageY - prev_mouse_y;
            move(dx, dy);
        }
        prev_mouse_x = event.pageX;
        prev_mouse_y = event.pageY;
    }
};

document.getElementById('map').onmouseup = event => {
    pressed = false;
}

camera = [0, 0];
var ctx = document.getElementById('map').getContext('2d');

function move(dx, dy) {
    camera[0] -= dx;
    camera[1] -= dy;
}

const image = document.getElementById('source');

function draw(time) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0 - camera[0], 0 - camera[1], 2000, 2000)
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
Example
<br>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="source"
       src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kthr8.jpg">
</div>
<canvas id='map' width=500 height=500></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what i need, misremembered what these arguments mean. Will accept this answer as soon as i can.